# match multiple patterns, return multiple substrings

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of search strings, and a target string that could contain multiple matches. e.g. colors:

```
search_strings <- c("Black","Grey","Green")
target_string <- "FooBlackBlahGreenBleh"
```

What's the most efficient way to get, as output, the vector ("Black","Green"); i.e., a vector of the subset of search strings that are in the target string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Vectorize` to vectorized `grepl`:

```
search_strings[Vectorize(grepl)(search_strings,target_string)]
# [1] "Black" "Green"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `str_match` that can take a vector.  The `vector` we got as output have NA for non-matches, that we remove with `is.na`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- str_match(target_string, search_strings)[,1]
v1
#[1] "Black" NA      "Green"
v1[!is.na(v1)]
#[1] "Black" "Green"
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  Thanks for the feedback.  I am not sure about the efficiency.  The `stringr` functions are optimized from `stringi` package.